# Xcode autocorrection tool?

Tags: swift, xcode, autocorrect, swiftlint

Are there any tool similar to swiftlint but with easy (15-30 minutes) way to auto correct violated rule?

Scenario: "Rule - comment should have space and Capital letter in the beginning"
Wrong line 1: "//line 1"
Should be autocorrected to "// Line 1"

Answer (score 1):

swiftlint has autocorrection. Just run:

```
swiftlint autocorrect
```

See https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint

Comment: I was asking about custom rules. Swiftlint has not editable set of autocorrection rules. All you can do there is to switch them on or off. But there are no way to make custom rule and make autocorrection.